# How to I calculate clock-angle on x-y axis using C#?

Tags: c#, trigonometry

We have a monitoring application that can monitor in intervals like 5 minutes, 15 minutes, 1 hour, etc. That's represented on the x-axis; The y-axis is also scalable and have values like 1.2345 - 1.5567 or can be switched to values like 26000 - 30000, etc.

Once the scale is set on the x and y axis, they don't dynamically change without a whole complete data refresh.

That being said, we only want certain people to be notified depending on the clock angle, of say, the last 5 intervals along the y axis.

The clock angles will never go counter-clockwise past 0/12; likewise, they'll never go past 6 clockwise.

I know the 3 o'clock angle is obvious when the x axis value is exactly the same as it was 5 intervals ago.

But how does one even start coding for everything in between? I can get the differences in x values easily (in the example graphic below, it's 0.3), and the difference in the y-axis in the below graphic is 4.

So with trigonometry that's opposite over adjacent, which means a tan operation I believe? If so, 0.3/5 doesn't seem to yield any values that seem like a clock angle.

Since I can't get any farther than that, I have no idea how it would be coded in C# other than calculating the differences.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: https://www.scholarsglobe.com/2016/05/how-to-create-analog-clock-using-c.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using atan2 ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) , [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.atan2?view=net-5.0))

From the wiki:

> atan2(y, x) returns the angle θ between the ray to the point (x, y) and the positive x axis, confined to (−π, π]

Note that the result is in [radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian), so you need to convert it if you want degrees

> As stated, one radian is equal to 180/π degrees. Thus, to convert from radians to degrees, multiply by 180/π.

Comment: Thanks! So if I use what you've posted with my example, it would be atan(0.3), which equals 16.699 degrees, ,correct? :-)  Then if we actually want to take it further and say where it fits on a clock, since it's positive 0.3, we then take 90 (degrees) - 16.699 which equals 73.301 degrees. Since each minute is 6 degrees on a clock, we then do 73.301 / 6 == 12.21 minutes. Does that sound about right?

Comment: @user11827463, just use atan2 to make it simple for yourself. You can flip the order and invert one of the arguments to use whatever axis you want as the basis axis. Or you can transform the result after you have the angle, either way works fine. I would recommend some unit tests to ensure you have covered various edge cases and get the result you would expect..

Comment: Regular `Math.Atan(z)` would suffice for this problem.

Comment: @john Alexiou You are right, my mental rule is to always use atan2 when doing geometry to avoid needing to think if atan would be ok for the specific case or not.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou, that's what I've coded tonight because I know the value of x will always be positive. One of the edge cases I'm having to take into account is to "normalize" all the differences to keep them between -10 and 10 since those are true valid values and won't matter what scale is being shown in the x-axis. My example has a difference of 0.3, but when the scale is 5 digits (eg, like 25k - 30k), and there's a difference of 2k, that doesn't suffice for atan, but 2 seems to according to [this link](https://www.rapidtables.com/math/trigonometry/arctan.html).

Comment: @user11827463 - Of course, doing this naively is incorrect. See my post for more details.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things here. First I think what you are asking for is the angle `φ` below, given two data points `(x1,y1)` and `(x2,y2)`.

[image: fig1]

The problem here is that the angle is measuring the indicated triangle *in pixels* and not in *x*, *y* units.

So **it is incorrect** to do `var φ = Math.Atan( (y2-y1)/(x2-x1) );` because the *x* and *y* axis have different units and angles are *always* dimensionless.

What additional information is needed, is the size of the graph area in pixels, as well as the range of values. Alternatively, the scaling `gx`,`gy` in pixels/unit for both axis.

[image: fig2]

For example, if the *x*-axis needs 45 pixels to span 1 grid of `1 hour` (`60 minutes`) then te scaling is `double gx = 45/60.0`, and if the *y*-axis needs also 45 pixels to span 1 grid of `0.1` value then `double gy = 45/0.1`.

Then you can use this to calculate the sides of the triangle **in pixels** before calculating the angle

```
var adjacent = gx*(x2-x1);  // convert x-axis units to pixels
var opposing = gy*(y2-y1);  // convert y-axis units to pixels
var φ = Math.Atan(addjacent/opposing) * (180/Math.PI);
```

The last part calculates the angle `φ` and converts it from radians to degrees.